# BlogEnginet.net to Jekyll migration without breaking URLs

Tags: url, github, migration, jekyll, blogengine.net

I am currently using BlogEngine.net as my blogging platform. I'm fascinated with the beauty and simplicity of Jekyll and want to move to it.

I have found 2 resources which help in migrating existing posts: http://doingthedishes.com/2011/04/14/moving-to-jekyll.html and http://philippkueng.ch/migrate-from-blogengine-dot-net-to-jekyll.html. I am yet to try these methods. However, I'm worried about conflicting URL structures, which can cause broken links to my posts which are referenced elsewhere.

BlogEngine.net uses the URL structure "***http:// sitename.com/post/title-of-the-post.aspx***". I'm not sure if I can retain the same URL structure after migrating to jekyll (I've checked Jekyll's permalinks https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Permalinks, but I don't think it can help). Kindly let me know how I can solve this problem of migrating from blogEngine.net to jekyll without breaking URLs and losing SEO ranking.

Edit: I want to host my static blog on Github pages, which do not support redirects. Is there a way I can use Github or should I choose a host which supports htaccess redirects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain the same URL structure with Jekyll. Add the following in _config.yml file,

```
permalink: /post/:title.aspx/index.html
```

Jekyll picks the :title from the URL part of file present in _posts folder.

Ex: File name: 2012-06-09-title-of-the-post.markdown, title: title-of-the-post

Since my [blog](http://aravindavk.in) is powered by Jekyll, I tested locally with this new URL format with .aspx extension. It worked.

Jekyll creates a folder called "title-of-the-post.aspx" instead of file, and creates index.html inside that folder. so no redirects required.

Comment: aah..treating ".aspx" as part of folder name instead of extension..never occurred to me..that's nice trick! Thanks a lot Aravinda :)